# Trying to condense JavaScript / jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to condense my code in order to implement the DRY principle, I have played around with the code a bit and manage to condense some of it but not all.

The area I am looking to condense is the lines with the code:

$("#modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {}

As you can see this is repeated throughout the file and I do not believe this is best practice.  I have tried to place this in a function itself but the problem I have is that when I close the video it still continues to play.

Not sure if the code can be reduced any further so thought I would ask for advice.

```
// Video Play
$(function() {
  // Auto Play Modal Video
  $(".video").click(function() {
    var theModal = $(this).data("target"),
      videoSRC = $(this).attr("data-video"),
      videoSRCauto =
        videoSRC +
        "?modestbranding=1&rel=0&controls=0&showinfo=0&html5=1&autoplay=1";
  $(theModal + " video").attr("src", videoSRCauto);
  });

  $("#videoModal").on("hide.bs.modal", function() {
    $("video").attr("src", "");
  });
});

function video(vid) {
  $(vid).attr("src", $(vid).attr("src"));
}

$("#modal1").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video("#modal1 video");
});

$("#modal2").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video("#modal2 video");
});

$("#modal3").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video("#modal3 video");
});

$("#modal4").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video("#modal4 video");
});

$("#modal5").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video("#modal5 video");
});

$("#modal6").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video("#modal6 video");
});

$("#modal7").on("hidden.bs.modal", function(e) {
  video("#modal7 video");
});
```

Comment: Is `"hidden.bs.modal"` an oddly named custom event, or did you forget an event name in event delegation, like `.on('click', 'hidden.bs.modal', ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use classes instead of IDs, and then you can select the `video` descendant dynamically, and pass it to `video`. For example, using a class name of `.modal` instead of `#modal1`, `#modal2`, ...:

```
function video($vid) {
  $vid.attr("src", $vid.attr("src"));
}
$(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function() {
  video($(this).find('video'));
});
```

Comment: wow, can't believe how quickly you answered that.  I've been trying to work it out for over an hour now!  Makes perfect sense, should have looked to target a class and use $this.  Thanks!

Comment: I would (personally, at least) argue that using `data-` attributes as JS/jQuery selectors and leaving classes for CSS only is better practice.

Comment: @Jeto That's the first time I've heard that, sounds a bit odd but not *that* odd, do you have a link or something I can look at to read an argument for it?

Comment: @CertainPerformance https://css-tricks.com/stop-using-css-selectors-non-css/ for instance. There's several arguments, but the main one is to keep styling and scripting as separate as possible. Also https://justmarkup.com/log/2017/07/my-approach-on-using-id-class-and-data-attributes-in-html-css-and-javascript/ (which is linked from the previous one).